# How to style, align content in React UI Semantic

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am unable to understand how to align content using the styles parameter in React Semantic UI kit.

I have defined the styles parameter like given below:

```
var styles = {
  navBar: {
    backgroundColor: 'dark blue'
  },
  left: {
    textAlign: 'left'
  },
  rightNav: {
  },
  verticalLine: {
  },
};
```

Below is part of my code which generates checkboxes along with labels. I need to left align those labels with padding between them and the checkbox.

```
<Form.Field>
                     <React.Fragment>
                             <List horizontal style={styles.left}>
                            {
                              womensBoutiqueOptions.map(item => (

                                <List.Item key={item.key}>
                                        <List.Content>
                                          <List.Header>
                                              {item.text}
                                          </List.Header>


                                       <Checkbox2 name={item.value} checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(item.value)} onChange={this.handleChange} />

                                  </List.Content> 
                                </List.Item>
                              ))
                            }
                          </List>
                    </React.Fragment>
                </Form.Field>
```

Heres the output.
[image]
The above code uses the semantic UI provided **List** component.
The second list of checkboxes is generated using the ul HTML tag as seen in the screenshot.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Semantic UI checkbox and its label should not be separated by a List.Header:

### JSX

```
<List horizontal>
    <List.Item>
      <Checkbox label='Make my profile visible' />
    </List.Item>
    <List.Item>
      <Checkbox label='Make my profile visible' />
    </List.Item>
    <List.Item>
      <Checkbox label='Make my profile visible' />
    </List.Item>
    <List.Item>
      <Checkbox label='Make my profile visible' />
    </List.Item>
    <List.Item>
      <Checkbox label='Make my profile visible' />
    </List.Item>
    <List.Item>
      <Checkbox label='Make my profile visible' />
    </List.Item>
  </List>
```

### CSS

```
.ui.checkbox label:before,
.ui.checkbox label:after{
  right: 0px;
  left: auto;
}

.ui.checkbox label {
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: 24px;
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/jlzrplm81w

Comment: Obrigado Mosè, you are a lifesaver.